# Apache load balancer custom probe

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

Is there a way to use a custom probe with apache httpd load balancer?

In the example below from the apache documentation, apache will determine the availability of each node by pinging the service port. Instead, I would like apache to call some /probe service which would return "ok" when the node is available. Is that ever possible?

```
<Proxy balancer://myset>
  BalancerMember http://www2.example.com:8080
  BalancerMember http://www3.example.com:8080
  ProxySet lbmethod=bytraffic
</Proxy>

ProxyPass "/images/"  "balancer://myset/"
ProxyPassReverse "/images/"  "balancer://myset/"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody has the same question, it looks like this is possible in 2.4 using mod_proxy_hcheck: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html